# How can we remove Exchange 2007 roles without a DC available?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2007

How can we remove Exchange 2007 without contacting a DC?

We need to remove the roles because we want to re-utilize the server. Our domain structure has changed and no DC exists any longer for that domain.

I'm running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I have to ask, why? Why are you in a situation where you are allowed to remove an Exchange server from your organization but you're not allowed to contact any DC?

Comment: We have been moved to clouds. So we are planning to use the same server for other database. As well as our domain has also changed. So when i am trying to remove exchange it asking for the DC to be contacted.

Answer (score 6):

If the domain no longer exists and you want to re-deploy the box into a new role then I would suggest that the simplest answer might be to wipe and re-install Windows.

This is probably the best way to ensure that not only is Exchange removed but that any other pre-requisites it requires or custom tuning made to the operating system over the years for Exchange performance will be removed too and won't clash with your database requirements.

Answer (score 3):

From [Manually Remove Exchange 2007](http://blog.koenvermoesen.be/2009/01/23/manually-remove-exchange-2007/)

> 1. Run `setup /m:uninstall`
> 2. Stop and disable all the Exchange 2007 services
> 3. Use Registry Editor (Start->Run->Regedit) to remove these Exchange related registry keys:
>
>    - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange`
>    - `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchange*` (all the keys starting with “MSExchange”)
>    - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Exchange`
> 4. Remove the entire Web Server role (don’t forget to reinstall afterwards as it’s a prerequisite for E2K7!)
> 5. Remove the Exchange 2007 server from Active Directory. I ended up deleting the entire “Microsoft Exchange” branch from ADSIEdit (Configuration Container > Services > Microsoft Exchange) as my Org only counts one server.
> 6. Use Windows Explorer to delete:
>
>    - `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server`
>    - `C:\ExchangeSetupLogs`
> 7. Use [Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) to remove all the exchange related info from the installer database.